Problemas al ejecutar Task Scheduling en Laravel con Windows
Estoy ejecutando por primera vez un Task Scheduling en Laravel con un sistema operativo Windows 10 y me genera el siguiente error:
2024-07-06 05:59:52 Running ["artisan" relation:prune] .................................................. 634ms FAIL ⇂ "C:\Users\Joe\Documents\laragon-portable\bin\php\php-8.1.11-nts-Win32-vs16-x64\php.exe" "artisan" relation:prune > "NUL" 2>&1
Pienso que podría ser temas de permisos en Windows pero no sé como solucionarlo, abajo dejo el código  de la aplicación (Me parece que está bien):
Kernel
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('relation:prune')->everyMinute();
}

Modelo
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Prunable;

class Relation extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use Prunable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'tracking_number',
        'shop_id',
        'user_id',
        'payment_id',
        'service_id',
        'amount_paid',
        'guide_amount',
        'bank_id',
        'payment_reference',
        'observations',
        'status',
    ];

    /**
    * Prepare the model for pruning.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    protected function pruning()
    {
        //
    }

    public function prunable()
    {
        return static::where('created_at', '<=', now()->subMonth());
    }
}

Al ejecutar el comando php artisan model:prune --pretend obtengo lo siguiente:
INFO  11915 [App\Models\Relation] records will be pruned.

Por el error no sé si es un tema de permisos para poder ejecutar php artisan schedule:run
